# Number of ways for a king to move from the lower left corner to the upper right corner by moving one step right, one step up, or one step up-right

Tags: combinatorics, chessboard

There is a king in the lower left corner of the $n×n$ chessboard. The king can move one step right, one step up or one step up-right. How many ways are there for him to reach the upper right corner of the board?

Answer =  the number of ways to reach upper right corner of $n×n$ board $modulo$ $1000003$ .

I cannot do so problems. I want to find a solution with combinatorics. I need help; I do not have combinatorial experience with these problems.

I have solution with loops but it is time limit.
$dp[i][j] += dp[i-1][j] + dp[i][j-1] + dp[i-1][j-1]$;

[Problem link](https://www.eolymp.com/en/problems/3175)

*Sorry for my English.
I do wrong something,sorry.*

*if I have mistake in something, please edit it*

Comment: See [Delannoy numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delannoy_number).

Comment: Thanks for answer.

Comment: [OEIS A001850](https://oeis.org/A001850)

Comment: If you want to be able to solve the problem efficiently, you already had all the math you needed.  You just need to learn dynamic programming.

Comment: but dynamic programming solution gives time limit.If i am wrong, pls explain dp solution

Comment: I messed around with that site for a bit to see how it would even be _possible_ for a dp solution to time out.  In doing so, I found that in the second test includes $n$-values of $10^6$ and $9969$, among others, even though the restriction of $n \leq 106$ is given.  Needless to say, I'm not impressed, but it's understandable if your dp solution is timing out if they won't correctly identify input restrictions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there is no up-right move allowed, then you need n right moves and n up moves. Thus, it will be the number of ways to place n 'Us' and n 'Rs' next to each other. To achieve this, choose n places for 'Us' out of the 2n available places. The answer is given by $\frac{(2n)!}{n!n!}$.

Now, let's consider the number of ways to reach the top-right corner with exactly 1 diagonal move. In that case, there will be n-1 "Us" and n-1 "Ls" left to be placed which will add up to $ \frac{(2(n-1))!}{(n-1)!(n-1)!}$. After placing these moves, there will be $2 \times (n-1) + 1 $ places left to make our diagonal move. So the number of possible ways to achieve this with one diagonal move will add up to $(2 \times (n-1) +1) \times \frac{(2(n-1))!}{(n-1)!(n-1)!}.$

Continuing in a similar manner, consider the case where k diagonal moves have been made. Then there will be n-k "Us" and n-k "Ls" to be places. After calculating that, you need to choose k places out of 2(n-k) + 1 available places for your diagonal moves.

This method is a viable approach to derive the final answer, and it works effectively for computation.

Comment: There are two mistakes that I identified in my method. The first one is that the king is already on the board so always put n-1 instead of n in my calculations. The second one is that after you place n-k ups and n-k rights, sometimes you can put more than one diagonal moves in the  2(n-k) + 1 places that are available. then we have 2(n-k) + 1 variables indicating the number of moves. so  we have $x_1 + x_2 + ... + x_{2(n-k)+1} = k$, and solve it for nonnegative $x_i$ s .

Comment: sorry,what is x represents?

Comment: @Isam x represents the number of diagonal moves in each place. for example, if your board is 4 by 4 and you have 2 diagonal moves, you have 1 Up move, 1 Right move, and 2 diagonal moves. So, there are 3 places available for diagonal moves. suppose Up moves happens before the Right move. then you have  .... U .... R ..... . but the problem with my approach is that I thought you can only place 1 diagonal move in each blank, but that's not true, because we can have U d d R, two diagonals in between. So $x_1$ represents the number of diagonals for the first blank and so on. $x_1 + x_2 + x_3 = 2$

Comment: Thanks for explanation.